# How to update a column value with by adding somestring in the same value (Snowflake)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Query I tried:-

```
 UPDATE store t1  SET t1.Name =(  
         WITH cte as (
             SELECT distinct(Name)
               FROM store where
               recorded::DATE between '2022-01-01'::DATE and '2022-04-30'::DATE
         )SELECT cast(insert(Name,3,2,randstr(2, random()))as varchar(12))
        FROM cte WHERE t1.Name = cte.Name 
      );
```

**Input table(store):-**

| Name |
| --- |
| ABC |
| PQS |

**Output table:-**

| Name |
| --- |
| AB34543C |
| PQ6756723S |

Random alphanumeric added to the middle of string

Comment: That SQL doesn't make any sense, so trying to reverse engineer it to suss out when you meant it to do is a tall ask. Can you share, in english (not code), what are you trying to do?

Comment: Can you describe what's wrong with your existing code?

Comment: Your code seems to be over-engineered. Just concatenate together the 3 parts of the new name and assign them to the name column in a simple update statement

Comment: @JNevill Actually, I have data with four columns. Among them, I want one of those columns to be filled with a wrong value so that no one can take levage of this data. In the end, we will be using this data to test a third-party tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So checking your SQL:

```
with store(name) as (
    select * from values
    ('abc'),
    ('lmnop'),
    ('qrstv')
)
select name
    ,randstr(2, random()) as rs
    ,insert(name,3,2,rs) as i
    ,cast(i as varchar(12)) as c
from store
```

gives:

| NAME | RS | I | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1m | ab1m | ab1m |
| lmnop | Cj | lmCjp | lmCjp |
| qrstv | j5 | qrj5v | qrj5v |

which can be written like you have it, but the cast can be tighter:

```
select name
    ,insert(name,3,2,randstr(2, random()))::text(12) as c
    ,system$typeof(c)
from store
```

| NAME | C | SYSTEM$TYPEOF(C) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | absU | VARCHAR(12)[LOB] |
| lmnop | lmhgp | VARCHAR(12)[LOB] |
| qrstv | qrJrv | VARCHAR(12)[LOB] |

So mixing this into your date requirement:

```
create or replace table store(name,recorded) as 
    select * from values
    ('aaaaaa','2022-01-01'),
    ('bbbbbb','2022-01-01'),
    ('cccccc','2021-12-30');
```

using this update:

```
update store
    set name = insert(name,3,2,randstr(2, random()))::text(12)
    where recorded::date between '2022-01-01' and '2022-04-30';
```

| number of rows updated | number of multi-joined rows updated |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 |

```
select * from store;
```

| NAME | RECORDED |
| --- | --- |
| aaKsaa | 2022-01-01 |
| bbwQbb | 2022-01-01 |
| cccccc | 2021-12-30 |